# What is the difference between 'Equation of motion' and 'Transport equation'?

Tags: terminology, definition, equations-of-motion, transport-phenomena

I think this is a simple question with a not so easily explained answer. What is the difference between the Equation of motion and Transport eq? Is Navier stokes equation an 'Equation of motion' or a 'Transport equation' (Transport of momentum).

Transport Equation has eulerian frame 'feel' while the Equation of motion has 'Lagrangian' frame 'feel'. ex: 'Flow' of a fluid or a scale may be given by a Transport equation while the moment of an air bubble in a flow is given by 'equation of motion.

Ps: I realize that the air bubble can be given by a phase 'transport equation' too while I have also ready Navier stokes equation described as 'equation of motion. So the name 'equation of motion' and 'transport equation seems to be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

The Navier-Stokes equation is the equation of motion for a fluid assuming constant density and constant viscosity.  The equation of motion for a volume element in a fluid considers all forces on, and the rate of momentum in and out of the volume element.  For details, see a text on transport phenomena such as Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot. For inviscid fluid the Navier-Stokes equation becomes the Euler equation.

The volume element is stationary, so the Eulerian viewpoint is being used; that is, we are not following a moving, fixed mass (the Lagrangian viewpoint).

Transport phenomena is a term that includes momentum, energy, and mass transport.  There are separate equations for these three types of transport; for example, the equation of motion for momentum transport, the first law of thermodynamics for energy transport, and Fick's law for mass transport. I am not aware of any generally accepted single definition for a "transport equation".

Comment: So momentum transport equation and equation of motion are the same for a fluid? Is there a rule when to refer them as transport equation and when to call them equation not motion?

Comment: I think for clarification I should also ask..if that means mass or energy transport equation are NOT equation of motion ryt as they don't deal with "forces"

Comment: The momentum transport equation and the equation of motion are the same for a fluid; this is the force equation.  In the literature, both terms are used, but for a general discussion of all the transport equations, momentum transport equation is typically used. Mass and energy transport equations do not deal explicitly with forces as you say, but energy transport deals with work which can be due to a force.